# wine: vboxvideo_dri.so: wrong ELF class

Tags: drivers, wine, virtualbox

I'm trying to run a game under wine. I want to confirm if it works under `linux`. I'm running `ubuntu quantal` under virtualbox (the host OS is `Windows 7`). The Guest Additions are successfully installed:

```
$ lsmod | grep vbox
vboxvideo              12612  1 
drm                   288972  2 vboxvideo
vboxsf                 43770  0 
vboxguest             235494  7 vboxsf
```

Here's what `wine` says:

```
$ LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose wine nhc.exe
libGL: screen 0 does not appear to be DRI2 capable
libGL: XF86DRIGetClientDriverName: 1.0.0 vboxvideo (screen 0)
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri/tls/vboxvideo_dri.so
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri/vboxvideo_dri.so
libGL error: dlopen /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri/vboxvideo_dri.so failed (/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri/vboxvideo_dri.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64)
libGL: OpenDriver: trying ${ORIGIN}/dri/tls/vboxvideo_dri.so
libGL: OpenDriver: trying ${ORIGIN}/dri/vboxvideo_dri.so
libGL error: dlopen ${ORIGIN}/dri/vboxvideo_dri.so failed (${ORIGIN}/dri/vboxvideo_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/dri/tls/vboxvideo_dri.so
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/dri/vboxvideo_dri.so
libGL error: dlopen /usr/lib/dri/vboxvideo_dri.so failed (/usr/lib/dri/vboxvideo_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
libGL error: unable to load driver: vboxvideo_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: vboxvideo
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri/tls/swrast_dri.so
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri/swrast_dri.so
libGL: Can't open configuration file /etc/drirc: No such file or directory.
libGL: Can't open configuration file /home/yuri/.drirc: No such file or directory.
libGL: Can't open configuration file /etc/drirc: No such file or directory.
libGL: Can't open configuration file /home/yuri/.drirc: No such file or directory.
fixme:d3d_caps:wined3d_guess_card No card selector available for GL vendor 0x4 and card vendor 0000 (using GL_RENDERER "Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 0x301)").
wine: Unhandled page fault on read access to 0xffffffff at address 0x75948050 (thread 0009), starting debugger...
```

Is there a way to remedy it?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've installed 64 bit guest additions in a 32 bit guest. You need to install the 32 bit version instead.

Also, just run the game on the Win7 host system instead of running it under wine on an OS it wasn't built for, in a VM, on top of the OS it was built for.

Comment: `uname -m` outputs `x86_64`. I suppose the problem is that the 32-bit game tries to use 64-bit video card driver.

Comment: If the game is 32-bit then it needs the 32-bit guest additions installed. The 64 bit version should not be in `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/` at all. That directory is for 32 bit libraries/modules.

Comment: As far as I can tell, `VBoxLinuxAdditions.run` installs in `/usr/lib64` if it exists, otherwise in `/usr/lib`. And I don't see a way to install `32-bit` version of guest additions. The game is `32-bit`, it's written for `win 95/98`. `Neverhood`, if that matters.

Comment: `apt-get install virtualbox-guest-utils:i386` inside the VM?

Comment: It doesn't seem to solve anything. You probably meant `virtualbox-guest-x11`, which contains `vboxvideo_dri.so`, which is in `x86_64-linux-gnu` directory if installed from `amd64` package. But then I get [the following output](http://sprunge.us/AFhd)

Comment: OK. Maybe the package isn't set up for MultiArch very well yet then. But you do need the 32-bit vboxvideo_dri.so in the `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri/` folder, rather than the 64-bit version being there.

Comment: Yeah, it seems so and ideas how to do this are appreciated...